# Trying to move a file from one location to other using scp command but getting error

Tags: linux

I have been trying to extract data from db using scripting and want to move the output to a location. Therefore at the end of  the script I have used scp to copy the file which is not working.

Error is "scp: command not found".

What could be the possible reason and how to avoid it?

Comment: Is `scp` on your path?

Comment: It's obviously not.

Comment: What distribution are you using?

Comment: @Suraj:  simply use the full path in the script.  This question, as formulated, is useless to anyone who sees it since it does not mention what system you're using, how your script is run, and the fact that it's simply about your PATH being set incorrectly.  You should probably fix those but in all honesty, it will **most certainly** make the question a duplicate of multiple previously asked questions.  The next time you ask someone a question, try to help yourself by providing a much useful details as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Either the `scp` command is not on the system, or it is installed, but not in any of the directories in your `PATH`.

`scp` is usually found in the `/bin` or `/usr/bin` directory.  Try:

`/usr/bin/scp`

or `/bin/scp` depending on your system.  If it is there, then look to add the directory to your `PATH` variable.

Otherwise check if scp is installed on your system, and if not install it.

Comment: If I am using this separately as a command it is working fine but when I use it in .sh file it is not working...Error is not there any more but file movement is not happening